# using multiple ajax functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use another functions at "complete:" JQuery ajax, after "selectOptionSort" function but doesn't work. What's wrong ?

```
        $('#tipos').change(function(){ 
            $("#marcas > option").remove(); 
            $("#marcas").prepend('<option>-- Selecione a Marca --</option>');
            $("#marcas").prepend('<option>-- Adicionar --</option>');
            $("#modelos > option").html("<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"#\">-- Selecione o Modelo --</option>");
            var tipo = $('#tipos').val(); 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASE+"admin/getMarcas/"+tipo, 

    success: function(marcas)
    {
        $.each(marcas,function(id,marca) 
        {
            var opt = $('<option />'); 
            opt.val(id);
            opt.text(marca);
            $('#marcas').append(opt); 
        });

    },
    complete: function(){

        $("#marcas").selectOptionSort({ //This works fine !
            orderBy: "text",
            sort: "asc"
        });
        //These two below doesn't work !
        $("#marcas").append('<option>-- Teste Adicionar --</option>');
        console.log("test");
   }        

    });
});
```

Note: I've downloaded selectOptionSort from https://github.com/yadhi/jquery-select-option-sort

Comment: Have you seen if the codes enters inside complete: function(){} you can do that by printing a console.log("Ive entered complete") inside complete function.

Comment: At "complete:" function if I put console.log or any another code before selectOptionSort all works fine. I don't know why after selectOptionSort the append and console.log doesn't work.

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to specify values with quotations inside select options.

Answer (score 0):

initialize selectOptionSort after you append another option to select box at your complete function:

```
$("#marcas").selectOptionSort(
    { //This works fine !
        orderBy: "text",
        sort: "asc"
    });
$("#marcas").append('<option>-- Teste Adicionar --</option>');
 $("#marcas").selectOptionSort(//reinitialize the selectOptionSort after appending
    { //This works fine !
        orderBy: "text",
        sort: "asc"
    });
console.log("test");
```

look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tyh5/)  under TEXT DESC for live example

Comment: I need selectOptionSort function initialize first because I don't want the appended text be sorted together. And the "console.log test" doesn't work.

Comment: @Leo I suggest you to have look to selectOptionSort documentation if there is any

Comment: I think  the selectOptionSort  need to be refreshed after appending new options

Comment: Please look the example of selectOptionSort: http://jsfiddle.net/tsurahman/VSABM/

Comment: This example of selectOptionSort works fine. Try with another browser. With Firefox works.

Comment: Any code don't work after selectOptionSort. I tried your edited code. No success.

Comment: the example that i gave you works on my firefox browser without any error it is weird :/

Comment: I went to check it gave error in google chrome console and it showed this: **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=-- Adicionar --]**. I changed the option text/value without dashes and worked fine only on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works for you as this kind of syntax is what I often use:

```
 $("#marcas").append('<option>-- Teste Adicionar --</option>');
```

to this:

```
 $('<option>-- Teste Adicionar --</option>').appendTo("#marcas");
```

Answer (score 0):

WHy don't you just do all the manipulation within one callback?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASE + "admin/getMarcas/" + tipo,
    success: function (marcas) {
        $.each(marcas, function (id, marca) {
            var opt = $('<option />');
            opt.val(id);
            opt.text(marca);
            $('#marcas').append(opt);
        });
        /* is known all options are there, can sort now*/

        $("#marcas").selectOptionSort({ 
            orderBy: "text",
            sort: "asc"
        });
        /* why append after sort?*/
        $("#marcas").append('<option>-- Teste Adicionar --</option>');
        console.log("test");
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this before. All after selectOptionSort doesn't work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You must reinitialize the `selectOptionSort` after each time you append.

Comment: I need selectOptionSort function initialize first because **I don't want the appended text be sorted together**. And the "console.log test" doesn't work.